# Trying to scrape a particular part of the whole HTML

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape out only the highlighted part of this:

[image: preview]

I am using the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getdata(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

htmldata = getdata(
    "https://www.emojimeanings.net/list-smileys-people-whatsapp")
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldata, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.select('td'):
    print(item.text)
```

How do I **scrape** only the required part of the entire `<td>` tag?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraper__, __scraped__) not scrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.emojimeanings.net/list-smileys-people-whatsapp")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

emojiDescription = []

for tableRow in soup.find_all("tr", attrs={"class": "ugc_emoji_tr"}):
    for tabledata in tableRow.findChildren("td"):
        if tabledata.has_attr("id"):
            k = tabledata.text.strip().split('\n')[-1]
            l = k.lstrip()


print(emojiDescription)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me to get the highlighted text-

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getdata(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

htmldata = getdata(
    "https://www.emojimeanings.net/list-smileys-people-whatsapp")
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldata, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll('td'):
    print((item.text.strip().split('\n'))[-1])
```

Comment: I got the outcome, but can you please elaborate what exactly you mean by the last two lines, I mean the for loop. I tried to understand but it is out of my scope.

Comment: findAll method is from BeautifulSoup which gets all elements matching. strip() and split('\n') are string methods in Python. I used them for filtering text

Comment: The filtered text consists of text like `U+1F576` or some other unicode at the end. How to get rid of that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use the name to look up the description, you can combine :contains with chained next_sibling

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getdata(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

htmldata = getdata(
    "https://www.emojimeanings.net/list-smileys-people-whatsapp")
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldata, 'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one('b:contains("Smiling Face With Open Mouth")').next_sibling.next_sibling.strip())
```

If not, you can use positional matching with `nth-of-type`

```
print(soup.select_one('tr:nth-of-type(2) b').next_sibling.next_sibling.strip())
```